# Function Question - Main Features

Tags: calculus

Can anyone answer these 2 questions?

Consider the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2e^{-x}$.

(a) Calculate local maxima/minima and points of inflection of f(x).

(b) Draw the graph of $y = f(x)$ indicating and explaining the main features.

Comment: I have tried to derive it and let it equal to zero to find he stationary points.. but i don't understand critical points...I know there is a max at x=2 and min at x=0. I get how to draw the graph but unsure about the main features and or if the man/min/POI are correct. Is there even a point of inflection? if not why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question (a)**

---

$f'(x)=2xe^{-x}-x^2e^{-x}$

Critical points: $f'(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow 2xe^{-x}=x^2e^{-x}$

This gives $x^2-2x=0 \Rightarrow x(x-2)=0 \Rightarrow x=0\vee x=2$.

$f''(x)=2e^{-x}-2xe^{-x}-2xe^{-x}+x^2e^{-x}$

Inflection points: $f''(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow e^{-x}(2-4x+x^2)=0$

This gives $x^2-4x+2=0 \Rightarrow x=2-\sqrt{2} \vee x=2+\sqrt{2}$.